# Bash input "read" stays open after Ctrl+C

Tags: bash, input, signals

**TLDR**:

`read` function doesn't stop reading the input after being killed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, instead it waits for user input at the end of another function that comes after the one it was in.

**DESCRIPTION**:

So I have a loop menu style script with multiple functions, one for every option in a menu.

Now the issue in one of my functions I have these lines:

```
printf "Enter your choice: "
read var_boxChoice
```

After the `"Enter your choice: "` dialog pops-up and the read function starts waiting for the user input, I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> keys to kill the function (which is trapped with `trap 'f_menu' SIGINT` command above the main menu function, so it wouldn't kill the whole script) and then I get transfered to main menu (as intended).

After that I select another function which has just this code in it:

```
    clear
    printf "Feature is not yet implemented! \nReturning to the main menu in 5 seconds."
    sleep 5
```

And then the problem occurs. Instead of once again going back to main menu, after the `sleep 5` is done, the `read` function from the first function awaits for the user input. I know this to be the case because of the input error handling mechanism tells me that the `read` comes from the first function.

What do I do?
How do I kill the input?

I am afraid I can't post more of the code, so I apologize ahead.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

For the folks who wanted the entire code, here is the mini example I remade just for that purpose.

```
#!/bin/bash

var_answer1 = 0
var_answer2 = 0

f_blah1(){
    printf "Whatever 1"
    sleep 2
}

f_blah2(){
    printf "Whatever 2"
    sleep 2
}

f_option1(){
    clear
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "What do you want to do?\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "1) Do this\n"
    printf "2) Do that\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "Enter your choice: "
    read var_answer2
    printf "====================================================================\n\n"
    sleep 1

    if [ "$var_answer2" -eq "1" ]; then
        f_blah1
    elif [ "$var_answer2" -eq "2" ]; then
        f_blah2
    else
        clear
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        printf "'$var_boxChoice' is not a viable answer!\nYou can only enter numbers 1 and 2!\n";
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        sleep 3
    fi
}

f_option2(){
    clear
    printf "Meh. I'm sleeping for 5 seconds. Then I'll return to main."
    sleep 5
}

trap 'f_menu' SIGINT

f_menu(){
    clear
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "Select an option:\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "1) Option 1\n"
    printf "2) Option 2\n"
    printf "3) Quit\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "Enter your choice: "
    read var_answer1
    printf "====================================================================\n\n"
    sleep 0.5

    if [ "$var_answer1" -eq "1" ]; then
        f_option1
    elif [ "$var_answer1" -eq "2" ]; then
        f_option2
    elif [ "$var_answer1" -eq "3" ]; then
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        printf "Quitting the app... Thanks for using it!\n"
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        sleep 3
        clear
        exit
    else
        clear
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        printf "'$var_answer' is not a viable answer!\nYou can only enter numbers 1-3!\n";
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        sleep 2
    fi
}

while [ 1 > 0 ]
do 
    f_menu
done
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], it's hard to tell what's going on from the snippets you've given.

Comment: How are you getting a popup dialog from a shell `printf` and `read`?

Comment: I don't think what you're describing is possible. The shell executes statements in order. There's no way for it to go back to a statement that was interrupted. But maybe I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @Barmar

I've updated the post with the "Edit" section where you can find the re-written nano version of the code, that produces the exact problem

Steps:
1) Start the script
2) Select the Option 1
3) Press Ctrl + C when the dialogue pops-up
4) Select Option 2

;;;
When the `sleep` function ends, the `read` function from the f_option1 will be waiting for input.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `select` built-in?

Comment: `while [ 1 > 0 ]` doesn't look right. It should be `while [ 1 -gt 0 ]` or just `while :`

Comment: @Barmar
It bugs out when used n^th loop depth, I can't get it to work properly.
This does work.

Comment: I think I see what's happening. After the command executed by `trap` returns, you go back to where you were when signal happened. So you're back in the `read` command.

Comment: You're not going back to the main loop, you're calling the menu recursively just once.

Comment: @Barmar

Yep, that is what happens,
But how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trap is simply calling `f_menu` recursively. When it returns, you go back to where you were when the signal happened, which is in the `read` command.

I tried putting

```
trap 'continue' SIGINT
```

in the `while` loop, but that didn't work well. After typing <kbd>Control-c</kbd> I had to press <kbd>Return</kbd> for it to work.

The solution I found was to put

```
trap 'return' SIGINT
```

in each of the functions that displays a menu.

```
#!/bin/bash

var_answer1 = 0
var_answer2 = 0

f_blah1(){
    printf "Whatever 1"
}

f_blah2(){
    printf "Whatever 2"
}

f_option1(){
    trap 'return' SIGINT
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "What do you want to do?\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "1) Do this\n"
    printf "2) Do that\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "Enter your choice: "
    read var_answer2
    printf "====================================================================\n\n"

    if [ "$var_answer2" -eq "1" ]; then
        f_blah1
    elif [ "$var_answer2" -eq "2" ]; then
        f_blah2
    else
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        printf "'$var_boxChoice' is not a viable answer!\nYou can only enter numbers 1 and 2!\n";
        printf "====================================================================\n"
    fi
}

f_option2(){
    printf "Meh. I'm sleeping for 5 seconds. Then I'll return to main.\n"
}

f_menu(){
    trap 'return' SIGINT
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "Select an option:\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "1) Option 1\n"
    printf "2) Option 2\n"
    printf "3) Quit\n"
    printf "====================================================================\n"
    printf "Enter your choice: "
    read var_answer1
    printf "====================================================================\n\n"

    if [ "$var_answer1" -eq "1" ]; then
        f_option1
    elif [ "$var_answer1" -eq "2" ]; then
        f_option2
    elif [ "$var_answer1" -eq "3" ]; then
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        printf "Quitting the app... Thanks for using it!\n"
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        exit
    else
        printf "====================================================================\n"
        printf "'$var_answer' is not a viable answer!\nYou can only enter numbers 1-3!\n";
        printf "====================================================================\n"
    fi
}

while :
do 
    f_menu
done
```

Comment: I see, that about explains the issue!

Thanks @Barmar!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to stop the `read` from preemptively activating?

By that I mean, in that exact same code, if I enter a wrong input such as "qwer" instead of 1 or 2, hit enter, and immediately after that hit enter one more time.
It will display "   'qwer' is not a viable answer ", and immediately after that "   ' ' is not a viable answer, you can only enter numbers 1-3!", which means the Enter is passed on to the f_menu once it is called upon. How do I stop that?